# Getting an error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException disconnected: received Inspector.detached event with Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, web-inspector

I am trying to run my automation script using selenium and Java and facing an error as:

```
WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
    (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)         
    (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024})
```

Can someone explain me the error please?

Comment: Do you think the information provided in post is enogh to understand and reproduce the problem ? Welcome to SO please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was automatically disconnected when the test execution was *In Progress*.

In the article [DevTools window keeps closing](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing) it is clearly mentioned that if you try to open the *DevTools* window when the *ChromeDriver* is busy executing *automated tests*, the *ChromeDriver* automatically gets disconnected and when *ChromeDriver* receives a command in disconnected state, it will attempt to close the *DevTools* window and reconnect back. Earlier Chrome's *DevTools* allowed only one debugger per page. But since ChromeDriver v2.x, it is now a *DevTools* debugging client.

If your *usecase* is to inspect the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) through the DevTools, the best approach would be to pause your *test execution* so that ChromeDriver won't close the DevTools. When you complete inspecting [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) through Chrome, you can unpause your test and ChromeDriver will close the window and continue.

As per the discussion in [unknown error: cannot determine loading status from disconnected: received Inspector.detached](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1194) placing the *ChromeDriver* in path solves the issue. So you need to:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: I have my Chrome Driver path like this:
 File file = new File("/pathchromedriver");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: I am having this error for the first 2 run after the 2nd run its executing properly, so still don;t know whats the issue.

Comment: @KASHIFAHASAN Your question was to explain the issue which I did canonically :)

Comment: Thanks for that but u have any idea how to resolve this issue.